# the phrase 'have you down to'

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of the phrase 'have you down to'?

In the movie, "As Good as It gets",

I found the line like this,

> 'Even then, don't come knocking. If it's election night, and you're
>   excited and you want to celebrate because some fudge-packer was
>   elected the first queer president of the US and he's going to **have
>   you down to** Camp David, and you want someone to share the moment
>   with. Even then, don't knock"

What does "have you down to" mean here?

Does it consist of parts "have you" and "down to".

Maybe Camp David is homosexual, and 'have you down to' means bring you to Camp David?

Comment: [Camp David](https://www.whitehouse.gov/1600/camp-david) is just the country house of the President of the US!  (Although it does sound like a flamboyant gay man named David!)

Comment: "he's going to have you (come) down to Camp David"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Have you down" comes from the idiomatic expression "Come down and see us" which means 'come and visit us'. So if someone is expressing a desire for you to visit them, they might say "We must have you down one weekend/day/sometime.".

You can also use 'up' instead of 'down' (e.g. come up and see us), but whether or not to use 'up' or 'down' is largely dependent upon geography and correlates roughly to whether or not you have to travel north or south. however, there are exception e.g. London, which most people have to travel south to get to, is almost always referred to as 'up' e.g. 'We're going up to London'.